# Can't get ng-show to show a div after the div's ng-click has hidden it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show

My hmtl code from my view looks like this:

```
<div ng-show="show_alert_message" ng-bind-html="alert_message"
     class="alert-message-container"
     ng-click="show_alert_message=!show_alert_message"></div>
```

I show the div initially by doing this in the view's controller:

```
$scope.show_alert_message = true;
```

The user clicks on the div to close it causing the ng-click to make show_message_alert false. This works great, hiding the div. But if I try to show the div again by running the command again in the controller it doesn't show:

```
$scope.show_alert_message = true;
```

It seems as if the ng-click had stopped it being possible to show the div again.

Am I doing something wrong? The scope for the controller $scope.show_alert_message = true; should be identical to the scope of the ng-click="show_alert_message=false" so I can't see why the second $scope.show_alert_message = true; doesn't work whereas the first one does.

Comment: are you running that command in the console?

Comment: There is not much information to give you a definitive answer, but my guess is that you have problem with parent/child scopes. Your ngClick is setting the property on a child scope and probably overriding your parent property.

Comment: I tested it in my angular app and it's working. maybe something else is messing with it. be sure not to use browser console cause that won't work.

Comment: make show_alert_message to be false when you want to reverse the action.

Answer (score 0):

I made a snipet and it is working as you wish. Look at your scope to see which scope are you using when you run `$scope.show_alert_message = true;`. I think this is the place to be fixed.

```js
var $scope = {};

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ngShowCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.show_alert_message = true;
  $scope.alert_message = "I'm an alert message!"
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ngShowCtrl">
  <div 
       ng-show="show_alert_message" 
       ng-bind="alert_message"
       class="alert-message-container"
       ng-click="show_alert_message=!show_alert_message"
  ></div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="show_alert_message=!show_alert_message">Show/Hide</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Does your code work if you run the $scope.show_alert_message = true; in the view's controller a second time (i.e. after the ng-click has run). I am not trying to do this via a button.

Comment: I did not understand your question. Where are you trying to do this? How are you setting `$scope.show_alert_message = true;`?

Comment: Basically I am trying to use a message div to show help information. On my view page I have several help icons that do an ng-click to call a function in the controller to display a relevant help message in the div. The first time I click on a help icon it brings up the message div as expected. I then close the message by clicking on it. So far so good. But if I press the help icon again it doesn't show the message.

Answer (score -1):

use `ng-if="show_alert_message"` and `ng-click="toggle()"`
and

```
$scope.toggle=function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
      $scope.show_alert_message=! $scope.show_alert_message;
      //$scope.$apply();
  },0);

}
```